# expect Interact reads the matched line over and over again without moving onward

Tags: linux, ssh, command, tcl, expect

I have the following expect script to:

- SSH to host
- accept password from user if required
- Once ssh successful (prompt appears), set an environment variable
- Once back at prompt again, run a program for network testing
- Once back at prompt again, exit expect and close ssh session

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
set hostname [lindex $argv 0]
set working_dir [lindex $argv 1]
set package [lindex $argv 2]
set tcl_test $working_dir/$package.tcl
set config $working_dir/$package.config
set logdir $working_dir/$package
set timeout 30
set prompt "\~\\\]\\\$"

eval spawn ssh $hostname
expect {
    -re "(yes/no)" {send "yes\r"}
    -re "password\:" {      
        interact {
            -o
            -re $prompt {send "export VARIABLE1=$working_dir\"\r"}
            -re $prompt {send "issue-test-command -config $config -module $tcl_test\r"}
        }
    }
}
```

The password match and interact works correctly. As soon as $prompt is matched, the environment variable export command is issued:

```
-re $prompt {send "export VARIABLE1=$working_dir\"\r"}
```

This is correct, but then rather than moving on to the line:

```
-re $prompt {send "issue-test-command -config $config -module $tcl_test\r"}
```

The same line is read, the pattern is matched again and the same command is performed. This results in a permanent loop of issuing the same command.

How can I force interact to move on to the next line, or use a different expect built-in to achieve what I'm after?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagine you're giving instructions to someone:

1. if you see a red light then stop
2. if you see a red light then go

You wouldn't be surprised if they get confused. That's what you're doing to Expect with multiple `-re $prompt` branches. However Expect just takes the first instruction you tell it.

Try this:

```
    interact {
        -o
        -re $prompt {
            send "export VARIABLE1=\"$working_dir\"\r"
            send "issue-test-command -config $config -module $tcl_test\r"
        }
    }
```

BTW:

1. you're missing `exp_continue` after `send "yes\r"`
2. you're sending the wrong number of double quotes on the `export` command

Comment: Thanks for the info, I've now got it working exactly as I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

If you provide the same pattern multiple times, only one of the associated arms gets executed. More complex things have to be written out in full (e.g., with a little state machine).

But I think you're making that code rather too complex. The only place where you ever really want to `interact` is once you've got the program started, and the only place where you might need a multi-arm `expect` is when there are multiple things that might happen at that point in the interaction. Let's write it more simply, but with the use of `exp_continue`. (I omit the setting of variables…)

```
eval spawn ssh $hostname
# Manage the login sequence, with its optional host check and optional password
# (that's optional in case someone decides to properly set up RSA keys)
expect {
    -ex "(yes/no)" {      # Exact match here
        send "yes\r"
        exp_continue
    }
    -ex "password:" {     # Exact match here
        send "$password\r"
        exp_continue
    }
    -re $prompt {         # RE match here
        # Do nothing; fall out of the expect as we're now logged in...
    }
}

# We're now at a prompt; make things work as desired
send "export VARIABLE1=\"$working_dir\"\r"
expect -re $prompt
send "issue-test-command -config $config -module $tcl_test\r"

# Now we're ready to let the user talk to the program...
interact
```